# How to set static variable in kohana

Tags: php, kohana-3

I use framework Kohana and I need to set global static variable which could be seen in every place of the code. Where may I declare it and in what way? (I think it do in bootstrap.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best way to declare global variables is to create config file File_name.php(your own name instead of File_name) in the application/config  folder, declare variables there and so we can access them in the any controller by calling Kohana::config ('File_name.Variable_name');
The code in my config file is following:

```
<?php    
return array(
   'Variable_name'=>'bla-bla-bla'
);
```

And don't forget to attach your config file in bootstrap.php by  Kohana::$config->attach(new Kohana_Config_File('File_name'));